# Robotframework: angularjs: unable to select a value in dropdown

Tags: robotframework

I'm using robotframework for automating angularjs application.

I have a dropdown with list of states. I need to select 1 of them. Pictures are attached

[Values that are available in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYbKL.png)

[HTML for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmTBY.png)

Could anyone help in selecting the value from dropdown?

I tried below

```
***variables***

${Residential_Address_State}    dom = document.getElementById('PD_Me_AddrRes').getElementsByTagName('span')[3]

***test cases***

click element  ${Residential_Address_State}
select from list by value    ${Residential_Address_State}    Victoria
```

I tried select from list by index and label as well, it didn't work. It clicks on the element, however it doesn't select the list in the dropdown i.e. victoria.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the item? e.g. `Click Element  xpath=//li[text()="Victoria"]`

Comment: I left a formal answer, please mark it correct, if everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click the element that you need

```
Click Element  xpath=//li[text()="Victoria"]
```

Also, consider using [ExtendedSelenium2Library](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-extendedselenium2library/doc/ExtendedSelenium2Library.html) if you haven't already.